# Umbraco: How do I include the generated files after install?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, umbraco, umbraco7

I have installed Umbraco via nuget to empty project.  I then ran the project so the installation started.

After installation ran there was lots of generated files so I have included them in project so that I can use source control.

I then ran project again and got the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'
```

There is the dll file for this in bin folder and also a reference.

I think this might be because the "packages" folder created by nuget installation is not included in project.  I do not know how to include this.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out problem was in the Newtonsoft.Json file in nuget package.  I downloaded latest dll from codeplex and it fixed the problem.

Comment: If you have (other) questions, you can also try the Umbraco forum at http://our.umbraco.org.